# How do I count multiple overlapping strings and get the total occurences per line (awk or anything else)

Tags: bash, awk, substr

I have an input file like this:

```
315secondbin    x12121321211332123x
315firstbin 3212212121x
315thirdbin 132221312
316firstbin 121
316secondbin    1212
```

What I want to do is count how many instances of a few different strings (say "121" and "212") exist in each line counting overlap. So my expected output would be:

```
6
5
0
1
2
```

So I slightly modified some awk from another thread to use the OR operator in hopes that it would count up everything that meets either condition:

```
{
count = 0
$0 = tolower($0)
while (length() > 0) {
    m = match($0, /212/ || /121/)
    if (m == 0)
         break
    count++
    $0 = substr($0, m + 1)
}
print count
}
```

unfortunately, my output is this:

```
8
4
0
2
3
```

But if I leave out the OR it counts perfectly. What am I doing wrong?

Also, I run the script on the file ymaz.txt by running:

```
 cat ymaz.txt | awk -v "pattern=" -f count3.awk
```

As an alternate approach I tried this:

```
{
count = 0
$0 = tolower($0)
while (length() > 0) {
    m = match($0, /212/)
y = match($0, /121/)
    if ((m == 0) && (y == 0))
         break
    count++
    $0 = substr($0, (m + 1) + (y + 1))
}
print count
}
```

but my output was this:

```
1
1
0
1
1
```

What am I doing wrong? I know I should be understanding the code and not cutting and pasting stuff together, but that's my skill level at this point.

BTW when I don't have the OR in there (ie I'm just searching for 1 string) it works perfectly.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `/(212)|(121)/`?

Comment: And I count 6 matches in the first line.

Comment: and 5 for the second! You should post that as an answer @ooga!

Comment: Haha ok I fixed the expected output. See this is why I am trying to make a script, because my sights fail me when I try to count.

Comment: Hahaha you are right ooga, my expected output was also wrong (see this is why I need to automate the task). I have corrected the expected output.
More importantly, your correction fixed it, I wasn't understanding how those slashes were working.

The final working script is:
`{
    count = 0
    $0 = tolower($0)
    while (length() > 0) {
        m = match($0, /212|121/)
        if (m == 0)
             break
        count++
        $0 = substr($0, m + 1)
    }
    print count
    }`

Ooga's first comment should be marked as the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making it too complicated:

```
{
    count=0
    while ( match($0,/121|212/) ) {
        count++
        $0=substr($0,RSTART+1)
    }
    print count
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
6
5
0
1
2
```

Your fundamental problem is that you were confusing a condition with a regexp. A regexp can be compared with a string to form a condition, and when the string in question is $0 you can leave it out and just use `regexp` as a shorthand for `$0 ~ regexp` but in that context what's being tested is still a condition. The 2nd arg for match() is a regexp, not a condition. `|` is the `or` operator in a regexp while `||` is the `or` operator in a condition. `/.../` are the regexp delimiters.

`/foo/` is a regexp

`$0 ~ /foo/` is a condition

`/foo/` in a conditional context is shorthand for `$0 ~ /foo/` but in any other context is just a regexp.

`/foo/ || /bar` in a conditional context is shorthand for `$0 ~ /foo/ || $0 ~ /bar/` but as the 2nd arg to match() awk actually assumes you intended to write:

```
match($0,($0 ~ /foo/ || $0 ~ /bar/))
```

i.e. it will test the current record against foo or bar and if true then that condition evaluates to 1 and that 1 is then given to match() as it's 2nd arg.

Look:

```
$ echo foo | gawk 'match($0,/foo/||/bar/)'        
$ echo foo | gawk '{print /foo/||/bar/}'  
1
$ echo 1foo | gawk 'match($0,/foo/||/bar/)'       
1foo
```

Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Even better, thanks! Many hours have been saved thanks to the good folks in this thread.

Answer (score 3):

The Perl way:

```
perl -lpe '$_ = () = m/(?=121|212)/go'
```

Output:

```
6
5
0
1
2
```